# Yii2 вывод данных из таблицы

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2, веб-программирование, yii

[image]

Есть разделы с жанрами. У игр может быть несколько жанров. Нужно вывести на страницу все игры, среди которых встречается жанр текущего раздела. Ссылки имеют вид `gameshop/platform?id=5`, в `action` передается `id`

Метод для доступа к промежуточной таблице такой:

```
public function getGenre(){
    return $this->hasMany(Genre::className(), ['genre_id' => 'fk_genre_id'])
        ->viaTable('game_genre', ['fk_game_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Не могу понять, каким должен быть запрос, что-то наподобие:

```
public function actionGenre($id){

   $query = Games::find();
   $games = Games::find()->where([$query->genre->genre_id => $id])->all();

    return $this->render('genre', [
        'games' => $games

    ]);
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сделать связь в модели Genre с моделью Games. А потом:

```
public function actionGenre($id){

   $genre = Genre::findOne($id);
   $games = $genre->games;
   return $this->render('genre', [
    'games' => $games
  ]);
}
```